# Trying to run C++ on Mac with GNU on MS VS

Tags: c++, g++, gnu

I've been trying all morning to get C++ to compile on my Mac, I keep getting these two errors, I've tried searching but I keep finding resources for windows, any help would be appreciated, thank you !!!
[[image: screenshot of MS VS1]

Comment: First thing to try, compile your program from outside of VSCode, that way you will know if the problem is specific to VSCode or is a general problem with your compiler. Next thing to do is include your VSCode configuration files in the question. Hard to help without seeing those.

Comment: You do have XCode installed which gives you `clang` as your compiler right? And you followed https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac?

Answer (score 0):

That's happening because VSCode cannot find the included file. You code should still compile. To get rid of those errors, in folder `.vscode` create a file called `c_cpp_properties.json`. Put something like this:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

`/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9` depends on where g++ is installed for you.

Comment: Should I type this in terminal ? Sorry I'm a very low beginner in all this

Comment: Just right click on the .vscode folder in your project, and choose 'Add new file'. You can create this file from VSCode.

Comment: Gotcha, just did so, and same errors still. I already did have something very similar in the .vscode file.

Comment: Is the path in your includePath correct? The directory in my path has subdirectories ```bits``` and ```ext```.